# Inline edit SQL Server database rows from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, visual-studio, ssdt

I'm pretty sure Microsoft have pulled one of the most useful features for performing quick edits on a SQL Server Database within the Visual Studio IDE. It seems to have only affected SQL 2012 instances, but from the Server Explorer I can no longer right click on a table "Show Table Data", pop open the SQL pane, query the data then perform inline edits on the results (as if I were modifying a spreadsheet).

[image: Show Table Data]

This means I now need to go into SSMS to make these kind of quick updates. Does anybody know of a plugin I can use with VS 2012 to bring back this functionality? It seems odd to me that Microsoft have two different development trajectories with SSDT and SSMS? Are they designed to serve different purposes? Can SSMS be integrated into the Visual Studio IDE? I'd rather have a unified development environment if possible.

Any thoughts on a workaround for this problem would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I know some purists would quiver at the thought of treating a database table like a spreadsheet, but semantically they are not a world apart, [plus this is supported in SSMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x6z1x9d.aspx). I'm more in favour of relying on GUI based approaches where I can to speed up routine tasks, why some would balk at this I have no idea?

Comment: Why wouldn't I? It's quicker for a start. If I have a bunch of updates to make across multiple rows on different columns, surely it's easier to run one query, place the cursor in the various boxes and over-type the data? As opposed to writing multiple UPDATE statements?

Comment: Quicker <> better. For one, if you make a mistake, will you notice? Also how do you tell someone else what you did, store the data change in source control, etc. etc.? And do you have any idea what kind of locks open table takes on the underlying system? If this is production you could be asking for trouble. Just because I *can* wash the dishes with a power washer doesn't mean I *should*.

Comment: But what about the risk of leaving a clause off an UPDATE statement and inadvertently corrupting a ton of data?

Comment: That's why you say `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and don't run `COMMIT TRANSACTION;` until you're sure. Are you saying you're more likely to fat-finger an `UPDATE` statement that you can review before executing, than to click in the wrong cell or update a row to the wrong value as you're hopping around a spreadsheet happy to be going quickly?

Comment: Mistakes can be made using either of these methods but the consequences may well be far more serious if a clause is left off a DML statement. Even with the locks on the table, with a narrow SELECT statement I can't see the advantage of manually creating all these different UPDATE clauses? Then again I'm not a DBA.

Comment: If you started a transaction before firing off at the hip, consequences are ultimately NULL because you can issue a `ROLLBACK`. You can't undo points and clicks.

Comment: For a two man team working on a beta web application (where data corrections are common place), this is overkill. I appreciate that this level of discipline would be required for large high traffic databases but it doesn't work for me. This functionality was always there in Visual Studio (and still is for 2008 instances).

Comment: Good and bad habits all start somewhere.

Comment: It's more a case of getting stuff done, furthermore it's documented and supported in SSMS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x6z1x9d.aspx.

Comment: Aaron, in what world is someone pointing VS at a production DB. Clearly this is a development\test environment where this kind of approach is suitable and appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install SSDT for this.

[image]

Comment: I'm running SSDT, the vital step that I need here is to first perform a SELECT query after viewing the results. With any sort of query in SSDT the resultset can't be modified. It works fine from "Server Explorer" when working on a SQL 2008 Instance, but not 2012.

Comment: After running a SELECT query I end up with something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/PTWUF.png.